# Android logs to server

Tags: android

I have an android 7.1 app that I want periodically to send the logs that consider my app to a server so I can inspect them. Is it possible?
Is there any app that does something similar?
Edit:
I already write the logs to files in a folder. I need an application that periodically sends these logs to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are different libraries (like SLF4J) for android which can be used for writing logs in files. You can configure them based on your requirement like log level.Then, You can write a work manager for sending this logs to server periodically.